# Powershell: Accessing the pipelined object

Tags: powershell

I am baffled a little, I can't figure this out.
I have the following code, it just replaces the character at the 2nd place with nothing.
`$list -replace $list[1],""` this isn't special.
However, I would like to know how to pass `$list` via pipeline and access it.
something like this:
`Command-With-String-Output | replace-some-how pipvar[1],""`

Thanks.

Comment: assuming that `replace-some-how` is a function that you wrote yourself, you'll need to tell it that it should expect pipeline input by setting `ValueFromPipeline = $true` in the `Param()` of the function and use `Process {}`. read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/explain-valuefrompipeline-in-powershell-advanced-functions

Comment: replace-some-how accepts the pipelined object and needs more paramaters. I don't want replace-some-how to "eat" up the object as I need it for further use as arguments

Comment: then you should do the replace stuff on a seperate line, and send the object through the pipeline after you replaced your stuff, or do everything inside a `ForEach-Object` iteration

Comment: `ForEach-Object` is what I needs then, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @SimonS

```
$list = "abcde"
$list | %{$_ -replace $_[1],"" }
acde
```

Comment: no problem, but just a thought, if `$_[1]` is e.g `b`, then all occurences of `b` will be replaced in your string. so it won't simply delete the second item in the string, if `b` is on other locations as well, but it will replace all of them.

Comment: I am aware of that, That's what I am looking for.